# mktemp on macOS random file generation fails: file exists

Tags: macos, mktemp

When I create a random file on macOS with mktemp I get:

```
mktemp /tmp/test.XXXXXXX.json
mktemp: mkstemp failed on /tmp/test.XXXXXXX.json: File exists
```

It does not replace `XXXXXXX` with random string. Works fine on Linux but not on macOS.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, for whatever reason, macOS version of `mktemp` supports **only trailing** `XXXXXX` for random string, in other words `mktemp /tmp/test.XXXX` will work but not `/tmp/test.XXXX.json`

Answer (score 1):

This is the documented behaviour, from [man mktemp](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/mkstemp.3.html):

> The template may be any file name with some number of `Xs'
>        appended to it, for example /tmp/temp.XXXXXX

Comment: yep, however, the behavior is different on Linux which isn't obvious

Comment: Well, the respective behaviours are pretty well documented on both sides. The macOS tools != GNU tools; if you find they don't behave the same, check the documentation, as it's likely they're *not* the same.